# Serializing objects runs too much SQL queries

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-select-related

I'm trying to serialize related field set to list. The problem is serializing a `QuerySet` is very inefficient.

```
class ZipCode(..):
    city = ForeignKey...
    code = CharField...

class CityManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().select_related('county').prefetch_related('zipcodes').annotate(
            realestate_count=Count('zipcodes__realestates')).order_by('name', )


class City(..):
    objects = CityManager()
    ....
    
    
    @property
    def zip_codes_list(self):
        return self.zipcodes.values_list('code', flat=True)
```

As you can see, I'm prefetching `zipcodes` so I suppose it shouldn't do so many queries.

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    county = CountySerializer(read_only=True)
    zip_codes_list = serializers.ListField(read_only=True)
    realestate_count = serializers.IntegerField(default=0, read_only=True)
    indexed_at_hmnz = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
    index_status_display = serializers.CharField(source='get_index_status_display', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = City
        fields = ['id', 'name', 'county', 'realestate_count', 'zip_codes_list','indexed_at', 'indexed_at_hmnz',
                  'index_status_display', 'is_followed']
```

According to the Django debug toolbar, it queries zipcodes for every object separately.

[image]

Do you know how to make it more efficient?

Comment: Is the manager actually being set? The code you posted doesn't show that part.

Comment: @GlennDJ Yes, it is.

Comment: Could it be, that values_list is ignoring the prefetch cache?
What if you tried returning `[zipcode.code for zipcode in self.zipcodes.all()]` instead?
From my experience, all() will try to look up cache first.